# assign params value to text field tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i assign a params value(date from params) to my text_field_tag for search form

In my form tag which has a text_field_tag as follows:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'date_from', Date.today.prev_month.at_beginning_of_month, :size => 10, :id => 'dis_date_from' %><%= calendar_for('dis_date_from') %>
```

I have assigned a default value to this tag

How could we possibly assign params value to this text_field_tag if a value(date) is not nil in params.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
<%= text_field_tag 'date_from', params['date_form'] || Date.today.prev_month.at_beginning_of_month, :size => 10, :id => 'dis_date_from' %><%= calendar_for('dis_date_from') %>
```